# How Can I add insert to my database with WP in my custom plugin?

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I am making  a custom plugin and I want to add fields to database(I have a new table create) but I don't be able do it.

I have my form this way, but  the action don't open file "page_options.php"

```
<form method="post" action="page_options.php">
    /* inputs */
<input type="Submit" name="send" value="button">
</form>
```

I think is issue of the path but I am not sure. I put this too but don't work too:

```
 <form method="post" action="<?=plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'page_options.php'?>">
```

How Can I add insert to my database?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to initialize WordPress infrastructure you should at least 
include wp-load.php if you are going to use naked .php file as a form action. Note that everyone will be able to execute your .php file, not only logged-in users, so you need to check that manually.

Much better way to implement plugin's options page is to use WordPress Options Pages built in functionality  for that.
See https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages for detailed description and example.

Comment: Thank you for answering me.  I'm going to see the link.

Answer (score 0):

I fix it with :

```
 <form method="post" action="<?php echo plugins_url( 'page_options.php', __FILE__ ) ?>">
```

But now any code that I type in gives error on the page:

Uncaught Error: Call to a member function insert() on null in...
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_redirect() in..

The code in page_options.php is:

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->insert('nameTable',
    array(
        'number' => '00000',
        'available' => 1, 
        'Id' => 11
    ),
    array('%s','%d','%d'));
wp_redirect(admin_url('admin.php'));
exit();
```

how can I fix this error?

Regards.